# Paypal Recurring Payments IPN

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, recurring-billing, payflowpro

I set up an IPN inside Paypal to hit every time a Recurring Payment using Payflow Pro is set to go through. How can I make it send back the variable for the custom ID I need to make sure that I can use to extend the membership?

So far I have tried ProfileID, payer_business_name, option_name1, rp_invoice_id, invoice, and custom, none are sent back when it goes through.

Answer (score 1):

The `custom` variable should certainly work, if it was included in the POST. Alternatively you can add any variable name=value pair you like to the notify_url, as long as they don't conflict with PayPal's IPN variables.

Comment: This is for the Recurring Payments, the IPN  is set inside of Paypal and cannot be set on the fly with this, so the variables in the URL will not work.

Comment: I've read that URL arguments in the `notify_url` are honoured wherever set. Are you sure that this doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

rp_invoice_id is returned in both recurring_payments_profile_created and regular recurring_payment IPN's.  Here's a sample of both.

```
Array
(
    [payment_cycle] => Monthly
    [txn_type] => recurring_payment_profile_created
    [last_name] => Parr
    [next_payment_date] => 02:00:00 Jan 02, 2014 PST
    [residence_country] => US
    [initial_payment_amount] => 0.00
    [rp_invoice_id] => 5416
    [currency_code] => USD
    [time_created] => 11:40:24 Jan 02, 2014 PST
    [verify_sign] => A0AUpo6gn8Mp.jtr-HUe-oSqCFb6A0LWR7wKLHmMMUUwszTktyPfL8DU
    [period_type] =>  Regular
    [payer_status] => verified
    [tax] => 0.00
    [payer_email] => blahblah@aol.com
    [first_name] => Don
    [receiver_email] => blahblah@usbswiper.com
    [payer_id] => F5T99998MN
    [product_type] => 1
    [payer_business_name] => Testers, LLC
    [shipping] => 0.00
    [amount_per_cycle] => 1.95
    [profile_status] => Active
    [charset] => windows-1252
    [notify_version] => 3.7
    [amount] => 1.95
    [outstanding_balance] => 0.00
    [recurring_payment_id] => I-WK69LR0DU8DU
    [product_name] => USBSwiper Monthly Subscription
    [ipn_track_id] => 6ddc294dddb3f
)

Array
(
    [mc_gross] => 1.95
    [period_type] =>  Regular
    [outstanding_balance] => 0.00
    [next_payment_date] => 02:00:00 Feb 02, 2014 PST
    [protection_eligibility] => Ineligible
    [payment_cycle] => Monthly
    [address_status] => confirmed
    [tax] => 0.00
    [payer_id] => F59999MN
    [address_street] => 96 east granada drive
    [payment_date] => 11:41:08 Jan 02, 2014 PST
    [payment_status] => Completed
    [product_name] => USBSwiper Monthly Subscription
    [charset] => windows-1252
    [rp_invoice_id] => 5416
    [recurring_payment_id] => I-WK69LR0DU8DU
    [address_zip] => 08723
    [first_name] => Blah
    [mc_fee] => 0.34
    [address_country_code] => US
    [address_name] => Testers, LLC
    [notify_version] => 3.7
    [amount_per_cycle] => 1.95
    [payer_status] => verified
    [currency_code] => USD
    [business] => blah@usbswiper.com
    [address_country] => United States
    [address_city] => brick
    [verify_sign] => AoumLIHoQx0AdOelHJVEVpKjHTDiArY--xdOStWxP3msX12oC3zHxpWw
    [payer_email] => blahblah@aol.com
    [initial_payment_amount] => 0.00
    [profile_status] => Active
    [amount] => 1.95
    [txn_id] => 5DL77590UR008354X
    [payment_type] => instant
    [payer_business_name] => Testers, LLC
    [last_name] => Blah
    [address_state] => NJ
    [receiver_email] => blahblah@usbswiper.com
    [payment_fee] => 0.34
    [receiver_id] => M5VRAQYEFCSK6
    [txn_type] => recurring_payment
    [mc_currency] => USD
    [residence_country] => US
    [transaction_subject] => USBSwiper Monthly Subscription
    [payment_gross] => 1.95
    [shipping] => 0.00
    [product_type] => 1
    [time_created] => 11:40:24 Jan 02, 2014 PST
    [ipn_track_id] => 8e2c922895e5c
)
```

If you're not getting rp_invoice_id in your IPN's then it must not be getting included in your API request correctly.

Comment: What does rp_invoice_id connect to? I sent ProfileReference and RPINVOICEID and it came back.

Comment: Ah, sorry, yes.  The actual parameter in the API request is PROFILEREFERENCE.  That value will come back in IPN as rp_invoice_id

Comment: May i know how to send this PROFILEREFERENCE in rest api code?